# Can you write transmission, reflection probabilities in terms of bra-ket notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I am learning about the transmission and reflection coefficient in scattering theory via [David Tong's note](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/topics6.pdf)  section 6. I understood transmission, reflection probabilities defined on page 186 as physical quantities (something you measure in the lab). Does this mean one should be able to rewrite them as something like $<\text{final}|O|\text{initial}>$ where $O$ is some Hermitian operator (i.e observable)? If so, is there a way to reformulate the example given on page 188 of [David Tong's note](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/topics6.pdf) in terms of operator and bra-ket?

This may be a silly question because one might say what is the point of rewriting, but I am just curious about the connection to the operator language.

Thank you